# Add local files to docker container during startup (not build stage)

Tags: java, docker

We have a project with sensitive information, which cannot be added to docker image during building.

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.12-jre-slim
COPY target/security.jar /security.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/security.jar"]
```

And in project **security** we have **certs** folder with *.cer files.

```
security/
   src/ -- source files
   certs/ -- .cer files
      test1.cer
      test2.cer
   Dockerfile
```

We cannot include this files into image because of it is sensitive information.
And we tried do it during startup container:

```
docker run --entrypoint /bin/sh security -c 'cp certs/* certs/ && java -jar /security.jar' security:latest
```

But got the error:

```
cp: cannot stat 'certs/*': No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe need look to Docker volumes?
Some like:

```
docker run <your_args> -v certs:/certs security:latest
```

Comment: The same error docker run --entrypoint /bin/sh security -c 'cp certs/* certs/ && java -jar /security.jar' -v certs:/certs security:latest

Comment: You already have ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile, so run like: docker run -v certs:/certs security:latest

Comment: but is better to specify a full path to the mounted directory -v /home/user/certs:/certs

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Could you please advise, what I need to add into file sharing? certs folder or level up ?

Comment: if you need to have a directory from your computer in the container, you need to specify its full path first, and the second to specify the path along which it will be mounted in your container <localDir_fullPath>:<fullPath_inPod>
Example:
  docker run -v /home/user/certs:/certs security:latest